# Add value from previous row under conditions

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I have a df `data` and I would like to add to a new column a value that exist in a previous column and row if the factor is the same.

Here is a sample:

```
data <- structure(list(Id = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"a", "a"), duration.minutes = c(NA, 139L, 535L, 150L, NA, NA, 
145L, 545L, 144L, NA), event = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("enter", "exit", "stop", "trip"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Id", "duration.minutes", "event"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = 265:274)
```

and I would like to add a new column called "duration.minutes.past" like this:

```
data <- structure(list(Id = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "a", "a", "b", "b", 
"a", "a"), duration.minutes = c(NA, 139L, 535L, 150L, NA, NA, 
145L, 545L, 144L, NA), event = structure(c(1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
1L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 2L), .Label = c("enter", "exit", "stop", "trip"
), class = "factor"), duration.minutes.past = c(NA, NA, 139, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, 145, NA, NA)), .Names = c("Id", "duration.minutes", 
"event", "duration.minutes.past"), row.names = 265:274, class = "data.frame")
```

As you can see, I added in this new column `duration.minutes.past` the `duration.minutes` of the previous `trip` for the same `Id`. if the `Id` is different or if is it not a stop, then the value for `duration.minutes.past` is NA.

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(data)`), grouped by 'Id', we create the `lag` column of 'duration.minutes' using `shift`), then change the value to 'NA' where the 'event' is not equal to 'stop'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, duration.minutes.past := shift(duration.minutes), 
             Id][event != "stop", duration.minutes.past := NA][]
data
#    Id duration.minutes event duration.minutes.past
#1:  a               NA enter                    NA
#2:  b              139  trip                    NA
#3:  b              535  stop                   139
#4:  b              150  trip                    NA
#5:  a               NA  exit                    NA
#6:  a               NA enter                    NA
#7:  b              145  trip                    NA
#8:  b              545  stop                   145
#9:  a              144  trip                    NA
#10: a               NA  exit                    NA
```

---

Or this can be done with `base R` using `ave`

```
data$duration.minutes.past <- with(data, NA^(event != "stop") * 
      ave(duration.minutes, Id, FUN = function(x) c(NA, x[-length(x)])))
```

Comment: Also a good solution, but I have more columns than in my sample :). but thanks!

Comment: @Floni  What is the problem with having more columns?  I create a new column using `:=`, so it will not have any impact on other columns

Comment: I actually tried your method but I edited it before to run it... so it did not work

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution using `dplyr`,

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 group_by(Id) %>% 
 mutate(new = replace(lag(duration.minutes), event != 'stop', NA))

#Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
#Groups: Id [2]

#      Id duration.minutes  event   new
#   <chr>            <int> <fctr> <int>
#1      a               NA  enter    NA
#2      b              139   trip    NA
#3      b              535   stop   139
#4      b              150   trip    NA
#5      a               NA   exit    NA
#6      a               NA  enter    NA
#7      b              145   trip    NA
#8      b              545   stop   145
#9      a              144   trip    NA
#10     a               NA   exit    NA
```